# Angular configure es6 syntax

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6

Im trying to get angular google maps to work in my es6 syntax.
In es5 it looks like this:

```
.config(function(uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider) {
    uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider.configure({
    //    key: 'your api key',
    v: '3.20',
    libraries: 'weather,geometry,visualization'
});
})
```

In es6 i did this: But i get that "configure" is not a function.

```
export default function uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider() {
uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider.configure({
    //    key: 'your api key',
    v: '3.20',
    libraries: 'weather,geometry,visualization'
});
}
```

How would i write it properly in es6? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to inject your dependency.

```
angular.module('yourApp')
    .config(mapConfig);

mapConfig.$inject = ['uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider'];

function mapConfig(uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider) {
    uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider.configure({
        //    key: 'your api key',
        v: '3.20',
        libraries: 'weather,geometry,visualization'
    });
}
```

To 'use' es6 i think you mean classes. If you wanted to use a class, use the constructor.

```
mapConfig.$inject = ['uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider'];

export default class mapConfig {
    constructor(uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider) {
        uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider.configure({
            //    key: 'your api key',
            v: '3.20',
            libraries: 'weather,geometry,visualization'
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But what if i already have one config? The route provider in this case.

Comment: you can invoke .config in multiple places. using component based design each component should configure itself.

Comment: hm, did not work. it says that $inject is undefined.

Comment: the projects is set up sp that i have one file that imports all controllers ans services. that works good. but i cant get the config to work for the map. Here is an example of how i have structured it: https://jsfiddle.net/c1kos1g5/1/

the mapcontroller works and logs "hello".

Comment: Any ideas on this @d3l33t

Comment: you only have to export if you are using the function in a separate file. using the keyword default implies there can only be one per export. this is a little closer to the desired style. https://jsfiddle.net/zsuc6Lcw/ Each file (component) should import angular and register itself