# How to monitoring a variable when change Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

How to monitoring a varible which is in a "service" module inside of a "directive" module.
I have a Service module.

```
angular
.module('SGA')
.service('messageService', [messageService]);
function messageService() {
var ctrl = this;    
this.messages = [];
this.send = function (message, type) {
    ctrl.messages.push({ text: message, type: type });
};
```

And i have a Directive module

```
angular.module('SGA').directive('message', function () {

return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {},
    bindToController: {
        msg: '@'
    },
    templateUrl: "assets/templates/message/message.html",
    controllerAs: 'ctrl',
    link: function (){}
} 
})
```

I want that when the variable "messages " to change the directive module is changed and sent the new value for templateUrl.
I need to be always monitoring the variable because when she gets something , I need to show on the page

Answer (score 1):

You need to inject your service into the directive.

```
angular.module('SGA').directive('message', 'messageService', function (messageService) {
```

Then in your link function

```
link: function (scope){
    messageService.send("hello");
    scope.messages = messageService.getMessages();
}
```

Look into promises to help time setting up your scope variable using services https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

Comment: This "messages" of "messageService" will be absatecido by an "interceptor". It would be provided anyway ?

Comment: using non strict mode angular will assume the service is available and try to grab it. If you want to be more strict with injection i would follow a pattern like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37396423/angular-configure-es6-syntax/37396615#37396615

Comment: I did not understand

Comment: sorry. can you rephrase your question?

Comment: I did not understand this part of an injection

Comment: This variable "messages " it will save the error responses that comes from " intercept " the server. When you give an error it will show on the screen. For this need is always monitorarando it